# second order non linear nonhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm learning about 2nd order differential equation atm, and I was wondering if there is any kind of a general way to solve a **nonlinear,** **nonhomogeneous** second order differential equation.

For example, I'm working on this equation: $y''+ A(y')^2 = B.$ $A$ and $B$ are constants here.

I have absolutely no clue on how to approach this, so could someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $v=y'$ to obtain $v'+Av^2=B.$ You can separate:
\begin{align*}
v'&=B-Av^2\\
\frac{dv}{B-Av^2}&=dx.
\end{align*}
Integrate once, substitute in for $y$ and integrate again.

There's no general method, I'm afraid.

Answer:
$$y(x)=\frac{\ln \left(\cosh \left(\sqrt{A} \sqrt{B}
    (c_1+x)\right)\right)}{A}+c_2. $$

Answer (score 0):

There's no general nonlinear theory. Not even for equations of first degree. You have to deal with them as they come.